# Where can I find a RESTful list of bars and restaurants close to a user?

Tags: google-maps, location, maps

I want to create a mobile application that finds restaurants, bars, and other interesting places close to a user.

However, I don't know how to find a list of all these restaurants and other places, without doing this myself. Is there some sort of service that offers a RESTful way to get this data? Does Google Maps to do something like this?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [new Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/).